# Flutter Arabic text dont render correctly in flutter_html, if one character has color and other not- QURAN TAJWEED ISSUE

Tags: html, flutter, arabic

I have string in html like this

```
<em style='font-style:normal;'>أُ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#d7d7d7;'>وْ</em><em
style='font-style:normal;'>لَ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#2144c1;'>ـٰٓ</em><em
style='font-style:normal;'>ئِكَ عَلَىٰ هُ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#169200;'>دًى مّ</em><em
style='font-style:normal;'>ِ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#169200;'>ن رّ</em><em
style='font-style:normal;'>َبِّهِمْ‌ۖ وَأُ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#d7d7d7;'>وْ</em><em
style='font-style:normal;'>لَ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#2144c1;'>ـٰٓ</em><em
style='font-style:normal;'>ئِكَ هُمُ </em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#d7d7d7;'>ٱ</em><em 
style='font-style:normal;'>لْمُفْلِحُ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#4050ff;'>و</em><em
style='font-style:normal;'>نَ </em>
```

Its rendering color like this

[Image:Data which html render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2kyS.png)

Now if you see carefully there is mistake in rendering,
Highlighted Mistake Image
[Image:Mistake Highlighted in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMXhQ.png)

it should render like this
[Image:What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLPZC.png)

I dont want color on لَ but it should connect to ـٰٓ like image(what i want).

This is becuase of this code

```
<em
style='font-style:normal;'>لَ</em><em style='font-style:normal;color:#2144c1;'>ـٰٓ</em
```

Is There another way i can acheive it, i have try changing the font but no luck, i want to acheive in this font also

Thank you